# How to maintain web application file versions?

Tags: jakarta-ee

Java -- Static methods to retrieve versions
XML, JSP & SQL --comments to add versions

I am using J2EE (JDK 5) with Tomcat 5 and Oracle 9g. Please tell me way to maintain the versions of each kind of files (Java, JSP, XML, properties, SQL and other flat files) in my web application. Standard way will be useful for future reference when new developer is going to change or add something after some years.

Comment: I'd really **hate** to see some static method returning version number of... of what? class? project? module? Shouldn't the VCS (SVN, Git, Mercurial) do that for you? If you have fixed staged at which the application is released, you tag it with the version number. The VCS keeps all the information about previous revisions / versions of the file. Or perhaps I misunderstood you?

Comment: thank you for your reply.but we are using StarTeam to do that I am not having options to get versions from that(StarTeam).Because about 15 years they are using like this so Please give me guidance to change with StarTeam.                                                                      PLEASE TELL ME REASON WHY THIS QUESTION IS STILL WITH 0% ACCEPTANCE.?????

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control

Also learn about SVN & GIT